# Can’t seem to install on second SSD, using EFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

/dev/sda is the SSD with Windows 10 on it.  It has an EFI partition already.  It is the only OS on that drive.

Trying to install 18.10 on /dev/sdc

I boot from a live USB stick (which I boot in EFI mode), choose ‘something else’, create 3 partitions on /dev/sdc: swap, EFI (500MB), and the remainder on /

I choose /dev/sdc as the device to install the boot manager (I’ve also tried /dev/sda, but same results).

CSM off.  Secure boot off.  All legacy stuff off.

Install always seems to work, but the grub install doesn’t do the right thing.  Hitting F12 during boot up, I can see my Windows Boot Manager (which gets me into windows) and ‘ubuntu’.  Selecting that just gets me a raw grub prompt.  That Ubuntu boot manager also seems to be installed on /dev/sda (in the EFI partition, alongside the Windows dir).  And I get stuck.  Every time.

I’ve been at this for a couple of days now, and have gone through more google pages than I care to admit trying to get it to work.  I use efibootmgr to remove the broken ‘ubuntu’ boot manager between attempts.

I just want to be able to power on the machine, have a grub screen come up where I can select Windows (on /dev/sda) or Ubuntu (on /dev/sdc), and just have it work.

What am I missing? D:

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub` command after Ubuntu installation? You reboot your machine, press `del` key and reach `BIOS setup` screen. Set up Windows bootaloader to top priority, then save and exit. Now verify that could you log on to Windows-10? Similarly, repeat this for ubuntu too. Please report the result to `@marmayogi`. Let us look into GRUB Menu issue subsequently.

Comment: @Marmayogi Can't seem to see a way to msg you directly (if that's what you meant.  Apologies, I'm new here.

I booted back into the live USB.  efibootmgr is reporting the ubuntu bootloader as being on the same disk as the windows bootloader.  Running 'update-grub' with elevated privileges yields:

/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.

'mount' shows (among a bunch of other things, of course):

/cow on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=//filesystem.squashfs,upperdir=/cow/upper,workdir=/cow/work)

Comment: After installation did you update your Ubuntu system with the following commands: 1. `sudo apt-get update` 2. `sudo apt-get upgrade` and 3. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. By rebooting, could you access `BIOS setup` screen by pressing `del` key? How many bootloaders did you observe there? Please list them.

Comment: I can't actually boot into the ubuntu system (or at least, I don't know how without a functioning grub boot manager).  As far as ubuntu, the closest I can get is to boot into the live USB.  I can see the installed system (it's mounted and I can see all the files there).  According to the BIOS, I have 'Windows Boot Manger', and 'ubuntu'.  When I select windows from the BIOS and boot into it, it works fine.  When I select 'ubuntu' and try to boot into it, I'm immediately met with a 'grub >' prompt, and that's it.

Comment: Please initiate a chat session, @async_fm.

Comment: Thanks! I’m traveling today, and may not be back to that computer for a while. As soon as I am, I’ll let you know. I will be attempting the same thing on a different computer later today ... we’ll see how that goes.